# Tap does not work inside didSelectItemAt, it does not response to anything. Can anyone help me to look at this issue?

Tags: swift, uitableview, collectionview

Here is my complete code. MenuTableViewCell is called from another controller. It shows up the data and picture. But when tap on a certain section, the tap does not work. After tapping it should go to a different view controller. Everything has to be done programatically.

#MenuTableViewCell.swift

import UIKit

class MenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
var Labeltitle: UILabel?
var colView: UICollectionView?
//屏幕宽度
let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
//屏幕高度
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

var arrData = ["旅游英语","商务英语","基础英语","成人英语","少儿英语","青少英语","视频","师资"]

var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    // 设置选中cell时无高亮等效果
    self.selectionStyle = .none

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    self.colView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 680), collectionViewLayout: layout);
    self.colView?.register(MenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "colCell")
    self.colView?.delegate = self
    self.colView?.dataSource = self
    self.colView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    self.colView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    self.colView?.allowsSelection = true
    
    self.colView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    
    //设置间距
    
    //设置水平间距
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    //设置垂直间距
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    
    
    //   layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (SCREEN_WIDTH/3), height: 125)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (SCREEN_WIDTH/2), height: 170)
    
    
    self.contentView.addSubview(colView!)

}
//加载数据
func reloadData() {
    //collectionView重新加载数据
    self.colView?.reloadData()
    //更新collectionView的高度约束
    let contentSize = self.colView?.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    self.collectionViewHeight?.constant = contentSize!.height
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.arrData.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell
    
    //self.colView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.title?.text = arrData[indexPath.row]
    cell.isSelected = true
    cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
    
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
    
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"luyou")
        break
    case 1:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"shangwu")
        break
    case 2:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"jichu-1")
        break
    case 6:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"shiping")
        break
    case 4:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"shaoer")
        break
    case 5:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"qingshao")
        break
    case 3:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"chengren")
        break
    case 7:
        cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"shiziti")
        break
    default:
         cell.imgView?.image = UIImage(named:"mainhead")
        break
    }
    
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if(network_status == 0){
        self.chrysan.show(.error, message:"没有网络", hideDelay: 1)
        return
    }

  let Publicmenu = PublicmenuViewController()

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
   
        Publicmenu.menu = "旅游英语1"
        Publicmenu.menucateid = 3
        Publicmenu.menubanner = UIImage(named:"旅游英语")
    break
    case 1:
        Publicmenu.menu = "商务英语"
        Publicmenu.menucateid = 2
        Publicmenu.menubanner = UIImage(named:"商务英语")
    break;
    case 2:
        Publicmenu.menu = "基础英语"
        Publicmenu.menucateid = 9
        Publicmenu.menubanner = UIImage(named:"基础英语")
    break
    case 3:
          let Contentlist = TextbooklistViewController()
        Contentlist.menu = "成人英语"
        Contentlist.menucateid = 86
       // Publicmenu.menubanner = UIImage(named:"成人英语")
          first_ViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(Contentlist, animated: true)
          return
    case 4:
         let Contentlist = TextbooklistViewController()
        Contentlist.menu = "少儿英语"
        Contentlist.menucateid = 84
       // Contentlist.menubanner = UIImage(named:"儿童英语")
        first_ViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(Contentlist, animated: true)
          return
   
    case 5:
        let Contentlist = TextbooklistViewController()
        Contentlist.menu = "青少英语"
        Contentlist.menucateid = 85
      //  Publicmenu.menubanner = UIImage(named:"青少英语")
         first_ViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(Contentlist, animated: true)
        return
    case 6:
      let videolist = PublicvideoViewController()
      videolist.menucateid = 39
      videolist.menu = "视频"
      videolist.menubanner = UIImage(named:"学员动态")
      first_ViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(videolist, animated: true)
      return
    

    
    case 7:
        
    let teacher = TeacherViewController()
    first_ViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(teacher, animated: true)
    return
    default:
        
    break
    }

    

    
    first_ViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(Publicmenu, animated: true)
    
    
  //  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tour, animated: true)
}




override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Here is the screen shot
[When I tap anyone of this section, nothing happens. didSelectItemAt does not get called.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaix2.png)

so when I click on the certain item of the picture the tap does not work. I have tried a solution self.colView?.isUserInteractionEnabled set to true or false. But it did not work. Collectionview cellForItemAt works. But collectionview didSelectItemAt does not work. I really don't know how to make tap working. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Does `didSelectItemAt` get called?

Comment: Hi Shim, thanks for replay. No it does not get called.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the collection view?

Comment: Yes, I did. As you can see the code below

Comment: let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    self.colView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 680), collectionViewLayout: layout);
    self.colView?.register(MenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "colCell")
    self.colView?.delegate = self
    self.colView?.dataSource = self

Comment: Is ‘colView’ non nil at that point?

Comment: I am not sure. How to check that? and my images and other info in the collection view shows up. Just the tap does not work.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check if it’s nil

Comment: Yes, Shim. I found this after checking with a breakpoint.  Optional<UICollectionView>
  - some : <UICollectionView: 0x7f9a2f871c00; frame = (0 0; 414 680); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000548030>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000bb91c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f9a2ed4a260>; dataSource: (null)>.        It shows dataSource is null. So it's nil. If so what should I do next?

Comment: dataSource and delegate are being set to self; they will be nil initially

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it does not solve the problem

Comment: Do you have any gesture recognizers?

Comment: Nope. I don't have

Comment: Are you familiar with xcode's view debugger? Use that to see if there's a transparent view on top of your collection. Are you able to scroll the `colView` and/or the collectionview that this cell lives in? At any point are you setting any view's `userInteractionEnabled` to false?

Comment: I will look into the view debugger. and I am able to scroll down. and userInteractionEnabled is set to false.

Comment: Looks like UITableViewCellContentView is appearing above the content of the table view preventing any of the collectionview cells underneath it from being tapped. How to remove UITTableViewCellContent?

Comment: Thanks a lot WrongWray. You have saved me and my code. After doing view debugging I found the error. UITableViewCellContent was blocking the tap. Setting contentView.addSubview(colView!) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing view debugging with view debugger, I found there was new layer UITableViewCellContent. This showed up after updating xcode. Instead of doing self.addSubview(colView!), contentView.addSubview(colView!) solved the problem.